# How to rename different named file with same extension in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying to rename a file from ".bml" extension to ".xml".I am able to rename with below code for one file since i specifying the path and file name.My question is in that folder,there will be more files with different name but will have same ".bml" extension i want rename all the files in that folder. since the below code will be static as i specify filename.Any help is much appreciated

Example as how the files will look in folder :

Test.bml

vbscirpt.bml

uft.bml

```
Set FSO=Createobject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strfile="D:\ExportedXml\Test.bml"
    strrename="D:\ExportedXml\Test.xml"
    If FSO.FileExists(strfile) Then
        FSO.MoveFile strfile,strrename
    End If
    Set FSO=nothing
```

The above code is able to replace Test.bml to Test.xml.

Comment: Use a loop and rename all files and parameterize your function

Comment: I did see your suggestion.But i am confused how to implement it :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [For Each](https://ss64.com/vb/foreach.html) loop to processing files and [Regular Expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_reg_expressions.htm) to change the format.

Try this way  :

```
Set fso=Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objRegEx = New RegExp

FolderName = "D:\ExportedXml\"
Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderName)
Set objFileCol = objFolder.Files
objRegEx.Pattern = "\.bml$"
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True

For Each objFile In objFileCol
    If objRegEx.Test(objFile.Name) Then
        NewFileName = objRegEx.Replace(objFile.Name, ".xml")
        fso.MoveFile objFile, FolderName & NewFileName
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

Although this has been answered, another way of doing this will be to use the power of batch [`ren`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ren) command to achieve file extension name change at once.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
strPath = "D:\Downloads\"
objShell.Run "cmd /k cd " & strPath & " & ren *.bml *.xml", 0, True
```